# Prevent Sound When Capturing or Exporting to Clipboard

Tags: windows, audio, greenshot

How do I to disable the Windows sound when Greenshot captures an image. 'Play camera sound' under 'Capture' is off. I must mute my speaker.

Comment: That's not supposed to happen. Perhaps you could uninstall it and re-install?

Comment: Not specified at https://getgreenshot.org/help/ nor in their FAQ. Suggest you ask them my entering a query at https://greenshot.atlassian.net/projects/SUPPORT/issues/?filter=allissues&orderby=priority%20DESC

Comment: I agree, this should not happen, and I have not heard a similar complaint so far while most users keep this turned off. Are you sure it's actually Greenshot triggering that sound and not some other utility listening to the PrintScreen key, like e.g. OneNote, Dropbox, etc? You could try to shut down GS completely (right click on icon - > exit) and see if it still happens.

Comment: Btw, I am sure that greenshot has *never* played a sound when exporting to clipboard, what kind of sound is it you hear? The only sound Greenshot ever made was a camera click right after capture, it is turned off by the setting you mentioned, off by default.

Answer (score 4):

Go at:

Quick preferences/Effects/Play camera sound

It stop the windows sound.

To stop the windows notifications:

Quick preferences/Effects/Show notification

Comment: Turning off "Show notification" worked but only going-forward, i.e. I had a bunch of captures already queued-up. As I saved each I still received the unwanted notification (and sound). However, new captures were pleasantly silent :)

Answer (score 2):

Turn off notifications for Greenshot in Windows, not within Greenshot.

Answer (score 1):

In the left of the bar at the bottom of your windows screen is the cell "Type here to searc". Input "Notifications & Actions", this will open the Notifications & Actions screen

Scroll down to the "Get notifications from these senders" section against Greenshot select "Off".

No more annoying pop ups and sounds.

Comment: This stops the sound - thank you, but also disables the helpful popup, e.g., that an export has completed, so not quite what I'm looking for (or what OP asked for). Still might help someone.